# Sql insert ignore does not work because of timestamp now()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to prevent duplicate entries like this

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO myTable( `val_1`, `val_2`, `val_3`, `date` ) 
VALUES ( '$var_1', '$var_2', '$var_3', now() )
```

The values i would like to check are the 3 `val_x` but because `now()` will be a unique value, insert ignore does not work.

How can i not check that last variable as unique?

note:  this is kind of like a cart, so i cannot make the first 3 values unique.  There is a session variable that allows each user to see a a unique collection.

From this diagram,  the first 2 rows are duplicate since they belong to the same user session.  The 3rd row is not a duplicate becase it belongs to a different user session

```
 +---------+-------+--------+
 | session | var 1 | var 2  |
 +---------+-------+--------+
 | abc1234 | aaaaa | bbbbb  |
 +---------+-------+--------+
 | abc1234 | aaaaa | bbbbb  |
 +---------+-------+--------+
 | 5678def | aaaaa | bbbbb  |
 +---------+-------+--------+
 | 5678def | aaaaa | ccccc  |
 +---------+-------+--------+
```

as paqogomez suggested i removed `now()` from the query and altered the table but it looks like i need a primary key for `insert ignore` to work, but for my scenario i cant make these 3 columns unique

`ERROR 1062: Duplicate entry 'aaaaa' for key 'var 1'`

Comment: What are your indicies?

Comment: If the value of `date` is always going to be `now()`, why not make it a default value of the table?

Comment: @paqogomez do you mean to change the column to a timestamp datatype?

Comment: @paqogomez how would i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Create a unique index on the first three columns:

```
create unique index myTable_session_val2_val3 on myTable(session, val_1, val_2);
```

This will guarantee that combinations of these three are unique, without taking into account any other columns.

Comment: thank you for the response but i updated my question.  I cannot make those 3 columns unique because this will act like a cart where different people will have collections based on a session variable.

Comment: @tq . . . If there is a session variable, how are you setting it in the table?  And, you can just add the session variable into the index.

Comment: a session variable from php

Comment: @tq  Gordon's answer, in combination with what you've done with mine will get you the results you need.  Try it out. (+1 gordon)

Comment: i still cannot make the columns unique `ERROR 1062: Duplicate entry 'aaaaa' for key 'var 1'`

Comment: @tq . . . That means that your existing data doesn't meet the criteria you seem to need for this table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i see, do you think i should post a new question?  not sure how i would fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest moving the date into the default value of the column.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE `date` `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This way, you can still deal with the duplicates in the data in PHP.  The alternative, as others have suggested would result in a database foreign key error if you attempted to insert a duplicate.

Then this sql would work and give the same result:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO myTable( `val_1`, `val_2`, `val_3` ) 
VALUES ( '$var_1', '$var_2', '$var_3' )
```

EDIT:

You still need a unique index to make it work.  See @Gordon's answer

Comment: hmm,  insert ignore is still inserting

Comment: I'm confused.  You want to make sure the values you are inserting are not duplicates, but you cannot make an unique index?

Comment: sorry for the confusion,  1 of the column is a php session, based on this column the other columns cannot duplicate. If `column A` is a session for user A then the other columns can overlap with user B because their session variable is different

Comment: @tq a composite key will exactly handle that. it is one index across the three columns.

Comment: @tq to illustrate, if you had a session var of `1` and `2` and `2` as your values, it would be unique.  Changing session var to `2` with the same values would still be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably define the `UNIQUE` keys for the combination of columns you don't want to be duplicated. So, don't specify column date as `UNIQUE`. Did you verify that? Define rest of three values as unique columns. It will probably work.